# cordova-2.9.1.jar Breaks My App

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, droidgap

I have a PhoneGap App and I am trying to add DroidGap:

```
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;
public class RestartAppActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

I also added cordova-2.9.1.jar to the libs folder. But now when I run the app MainActivity will not start. The error is
L java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field launchUrl of type Ljava/lang/String
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: 2.9.1 is _really_ old! Is there a reason you need to use such an old version?

Comment: Thanks Kerri! DroidGap removed in the latest. It's the first time I'm using Phonegap, trying to add a patch to an app. Any alternatives for DroidGap?

Comment: start by reading the getting started https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted and then the docs https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/.